# How can I create a link based on this format: google->someword?

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

I want to create links, based on a specific format.

When I type this:
    google->apple

I want get get this link:

```
https://www.google.hu/search?q=apple
```

I tried this way, but unfortunately it is not working:

```
//Intelligent actions start
function replace(){
   var str = $('.smile').html();
     var re = /google->([^ \n$]+)/g;
     var url = "https://www.google.hu/search?q=" + re.exec(str)[1];
    }

  //Intelligent actions end
```

**Update**

Based @vinayakj answer, I start create a solution for this:

```
//Intelligent actions start


 function googleSearch(val){
      var url = "https://www.google.hu/search?q=" + val.split('->')[1];
      alert(url)
      //location.href = url;
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  googleSearch($('.comment-content p').text())
  $( ".comment-content p" ).replaceWith( "<a href='url'>url</a>" );
  }); 
  //Intelligent actions end
```

And looks like replacewith function reaplce all content in

```
.comment-content p
```

with:

```
<a href="url">url</a>
```

And this function it has some problem:

1. Reaplce all text even if dosen't find this sting in div:

   google-->some word
2. The link is absolute incorrect becouse I get back this value everywhere:

   ```
   <a href="url">url</a>
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you do anything with `url` afterwards? The problem might be there.  `/google->(\S+)/g` is shorter, by the way.

Comment: Nope, this the all function.
I know, may be I need to do something with DOM manipulation, I just dosen't know how can I manipulate exactly based on this function.
I see this post:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_replacechild.asp
But I think is, this not this function which I need for me

Comment: I've tested your code and it works. As @minitech said, you just need to return the value or do something with it (add a `console.log(url)` after `var url` and see for yourself

Comment: Is it google-> or google-->, e.g. one or two dashes?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function googleSearch(val){
      var url = "https://www.google.hu/search?q=" + val.split('->')[1];
      alert(url)
      location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="googleSearch(this.value)" type=text>
```

Comment: This dosen't work.

The string stayed words.

I tested this in here:

http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/teszt-oldal/comment-page-6/#comments

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Errors in the console? Also where do wee test this on you page if we do not speak hungarian?

Comment: No concole erorrs, just I not get this link from the last comment:
https://www.google.hu/search?q=alma

Comment: I not see this answer working.
I mean I typed this word to input:
"google->Alma"
But I dosen't get back this link:
https://www.google.hu/search?q=alma

Comment: @vinayakj I agree. It must be a wp issue

Comment: Okey, I tryed this way:

http://pastebin.com/cQdsHZTN

And I finely get a erorr messange:


all.js:220 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: I keep digging, But I think I on the good way with this code: pastebin.com/DPsXZuZf Now Only need to do finding out how can I replace with actual html format Like <a href="https://www.google.hu/search?q=alma">https://www.google.hu/search?q=alma</‌​a>

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final solution after all your comments

```
var urls = { 
  "google":"https://google.com/search?q=@", 
  "bing":"https://....q=@&bla=bla"};
function getUrl(str) { 
  var parts = str.split("->"); 
  var url = urls[parts[0]].replace("@",encodeURI(parts[1]));
  return = $("<a/>",{href: url, class:parts[0]+"-search"}).text("Keresés ..."+parts[1]);
} 
$(function() {
  $("div.comment-content > p.smile").each(function() {
    var $link = getLink($(this).text());
    $(this).html($link);
  });
});
```

---

Old answer

```js
var urls = { 
  "google":"https://google.com/search?q=@", 
  "bing":"https://....q=@&bla=bla"};
function getUrl(str) { 
  var parts = str.split("->"); 
  return urls[parts[0]].replace("@",parts[1]);
} 
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit=function() {
    var str = document.getElementById("q").value;
    var url = getUrl(str);
    if (url) alert(url); // location.href=url; 
    return false; // cancel the submit
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id="q" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: this ones generalized answer.. OP should go for this one

Comment: I cannot test on your page from my mobile - any errors?, are you using an iframe? Google does not allow that. It works here as you can see. I go to bed

Comment: the codes are correct @HerbáriaBalance.. you are missing something else

Comment: @vinayakj I see the alert this part working fine (On run code snipset ), but I not see this code replace the text inside ".smile" paragraph on comment div.
I need to use class, becouse we have more than just one comment on this page.

Comment: caught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: `$( document ).ready(function() {
var urls = { 
  "google":"https://google.com/search?q=@", 
  "bing":"https://....q=@&bla=bla"};
function getUrl(str) { 
  var parts = str.split("->"); 
  return urls[parts[0]].replace("@",parts[1]);
} 
  
  $(function() {
  $(".smile").each(function() {
    $(this).html(getUrl($(this).text()));
  });
});
  
  
  });`
This code come this erorr:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
If I not combinate two function the getUrl is be a undefined function

Comment: I keep digging, But I think I on the good way with this code:
http://pastebin.com/DPsXZuZf
Now Only need to do finding out how can I replace with actual html format
Like `<a href="https://www.google.hu/search?q=alma">https://www.google.hu/search?q=alma</a>`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, but thanks for everybody:

```
$("div.comment-content > p.smile").each(function(){
  var original = $(this).text();
  var replaced = original.replace(/google->([^.\n$]+)/gi, '<a class="google-search" href="https://www.google.hu/search?q=$1" target="_blank">Keresés a googleben erre: $1</a>' );
  $(this).html(replaced);
  console.log("replaced: "+replaced);
});
$("a.google-search").each( function() {
   this.href = this.href.replace(/\s/g,"%20");
});
```

Comment: And if I whant to expand replace method, only need to to add a new replace method.
Like this:
http://pastebin.com/JvU6TBR2

Comment: `this.href.replace(/\s/g,"%20");` instead you should use `encodeURICOmponent`, special character cant always be space.

Comment: BTW the question you asked has the either answer, by @ mplugjan or mine.. just saying.. Its upto you which one to mark as accepted, these two or your own answer

Comment: I agree. This solution is inefficient.